# Stop Bootstrap Carousel autoslide on mobileview without javascript

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, carousel, slide

Is there a possibility to stop the autoslide when im on my mobile view.
If it´s possible with css... maybe with mediaquery xs and than manipulate a carousel element ...?

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- LOGO -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row logo">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-12"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/logo.png" alt=""/></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- POINTS -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- SLIDEWRAPPER -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/headbild-1.jpg" alt="headbild1">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/headbild-2.jpg" alt="headbild2">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/headbild-1.jpg" alt="headbild3">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/headbild-2.jpg" alt="headbild4">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- PREV/NEXT Controls -->
    <div class="container hidden-xs">
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="previcon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control pull-right" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="nexticon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: i added the code dito

Answer (score 0):

well to stop autoslide on a mobile device you would need to adjust your javascript / the init from the carousel in a different media query.

do you have a possibility to check your media screen size in js? if yes, simply destroy your carousel (sth like `$('#carousel').destroy();`) and reinit without the autoslide.

Comment: no there is no possibility to check your media screen size in js... and how i said i dotn want to use js for this